# Prevent snap between Android tween animations

Tags: android, animation, tween

I have a series of animations that I call in series like so:

```
final Animation anim1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(thisObject, R.anim.animation1);
final Animation anim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(thisObject, R.anim.animation2);
final Animation anim3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(thisObject, R.anim.animation3);
final Animation anim4 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(thisObject, R.anim.animation4);

anim1.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() 
{                   
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }                   
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
    {
        image.startAnimation(anim2);                        
    }
});

anim2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() 
{                   
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }                   
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
    {
        image.startAnimation(anim3);                        
    }
});

// etc...

view.startAnimation(anim1);
```

While this works, the image snaps back to its original position for a split second between each animation.  I've defined `android:fillAfter` as `true` in all my animation XML files, but this doesn't seem to change anything.  Is there a way to prevent this snap between animations?  Or is there a better way to achieve the same effect?